# How do I get the width of the taskbar without using win32api? Python 3.7

Tags: python, pyautogui, customtkinter

I'm having a problem where I'm trying to set my window height to full screen but I also want to use .overrideredirect(True), but doing this makes the window also cover the taskbar. So I've decided to get the width of the taskbar and subtract it from the width of the entire screen and use that as the width of the screen.

Everything that I could find about this problem included win32api, but win32api doesn't work on my version of python 3.7 or higher. I'm also using pyautogui to get the full screen resolution.

Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.title('custom title bar')
# Get full screen resolution
print(pyautogui.size())
winSize = pyautogui.size()
# Convert it to a string
winSizeStr = str(winSize)
# Split it to width and height
WinX, WinY = winSizeStr.split(' ', 1)
# Removing the extra
winXstr = WinX.replace("Size(width=", "")
winYstr = WinY.replace("height=", "")
winXstrGeo = winXstr.replace(",", "")
winYstrGeo = winYstr.replace(")", "")
# Print the width and height
print(winXstrGeo)
print(winYstrGeo)
# Use the width and height in the window width and height and spawn the window at 0,0 of the screen
root.geometry(f"{winXstrGeo}x{winYstrGeo}+0+0")

# Remove Title Bar
root.overrideredirect(True)

# Create Fake Title Bar
title_bar = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root, corner_radius=0)
title_bar.pack()

# Titlebar name

title_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=title_bar, text="custom title bar", width=1633)
title_label.pack(pady=2, padx=0, side='left')

# Close button

close = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="X", fg_color="#202020", hover_color="#ff1c1c", width=30, corner_radius=0, command=root.quit)
close.pack(pady=0, padx=0, side='right')

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I don't know of any reason why win32api wouldn't work with Python 3.7. Without using Windows API, you'll have to take a screen shot and measure taskbar height with an image viewing program (like MS Paint). The downside of this approach is it will only work on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code with Python 3.11.1 and 3.7.9:

```py
import customtkinter
import ctypes

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.title('custom title bar')

screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight() - ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(48)

# Use the width and height in the window width and height and spawn the window at 0,0 of the screen
root.geometry(f"{root.winfo_screenwidth()}x{screen_height}+0+0")

# Remove Title Bar
root.overrideredirect(True)

# Create Fake Title Bar
title_bar = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root, corner_radius=0)
title_bar.pack()

# Titlebar name

title_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(
    master=title_bar, text="custom title bar", width=1633)
title_label.pack(pady=2, padx=0, side='left')

# Close button

close = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="X", fg_color="#202020",
                                hover_color="#ff1c1c", width=30, corner_radius=0, command=root.quit)
close.pack(pady=0, padx=0, side='right')

root.mainloop()
```

Alternatively you could also do it like this:

```
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight() - 40
root.geometry(f"{root.winfo_screenwidth()}x{screen_height}+0+0")
```

This should also work but only on Windows with a 100% aspect ratio and standard taskbar settings. If you use 150% then its 60 and for 200% it's 80.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that i have my taskbar stationed on the left. But this does work on a display with the taskbar at the bottom. But is there anyway I can change it dynamically?